# Can i pass an own array trough the options from controller to formType

Tags: forms, symfony4

I want to pass an array through this function:
$form = $this->createForm(ProductTypeType::class, $productType, $options);

In symfony4 it seams not possible to pass own parameter through the $otions to the formType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible as you describe. Here is an example:

```
$form = $this->createForm(
    EntityType::class,
    $entity,
    ['optionOne' => true] //this is the array of options (in this case just one)
);
```

In `EntityType` you could then use this option like this (for example, add a field):

```
if($options["optionOne"]){
     $builder
         ->add('addedField')
//....or do something else...
```

Also in `EntityType` don't forget to set the default value for your option:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Entity::class,
        'optionOne' => false,
    ]);
}
```